# My django's website on cpanel doesn't load my media files( images upload from admin ) but all my stacticfiles (css,etc)work when DEBUG= False

Tags: python, django, apache, cpanel

I have a django project that works very well and shows all media files uploaded from the admin when debug = True but immediately i turn change to debug = False django cannot find my media folder yet it loads my static folder. as you can see i have set up my MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL correctly.

My settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
import os
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')


#HTTPS SETTING
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('appMain.urls',namespace='main')),
    path('auth/', include('appAuth.urls',namespace='auth')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),
    
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So i need some help to display my media files when debug= False

Answer (score 2):

make this in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

  

if DEBUG:

  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

else:

  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

  

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and in urls.py import

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.conf import settings

from django.views.static import serve
```

and paste this in your urlspatterns whith your path

```
  url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).